# Play/Pause buttons in a game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

MY code:

```
-(SKSpriteNode*) pauseButton
{
    SKSpriteNode* pauseButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pausebutton"];

    pauseButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) -30,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 30);
    pauseButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    pauseButton.name = @"pauseButton";
    pauseButton.zPosition = 160;

    return pauseButton;


}


-(SKSpriteNode*) playButton
{
    SKSpriteNode* playButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"playbutton"];

    playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)- 30, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 30);
    playButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    playButton.name = @"playButton";
    playButton.zPosition = -10;

    return playButton;


}
```

In touchesBegan:

```
    SKSpriteNode *pauseButton = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"pauseButton"];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];


        if (!(gameIsOver))
        {

            if([pauseButton containsPoint:location])
            {
                if (self.scene.view.paused==YES)
                {

                    [myTimer start];

                    pauseButton.zPosition = 160;
                    [self childNodeWithName:@"playButton"].zPosition = -10;
                    self.scene.view.paused = NO;

                }
                else if (self.scene.view.paused ==NO)
                {

                    pauseButton.zPosition = -10;
                    [self childNodeWithName:@"playButton"].zPosition = 160;

                    [myTimer pause];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(pauseGame) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.01];
                }
            }


-(void) pauseGame

{

   self.scene.view.paused = YES;



}
```

My problems:

1. I do not want to use:  `[self performSelector:@selector(pauseGame) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.01];` as its not accurate. I want to set `self.scene.view.paused = YES;` as soon as someone clicks the pause button. However, not setting a delay doesn't let the pause button change to play. Is there a way I can fix this.
2. Sometimes, my pause button doesn't change to play. I dont know why. This is rare though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you explain why is this: "not setting a delay doesn't let the pause button change to play" -- your touchesBegan method is longer that what you show and it uses `self.scene.view.paused`?

Comment: if i replace [self performSelector:@selector(pauseGame) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.01] by self.scene.view.paused = YES, the code within: else if (self.scene.view.paused ==NO) {} doesn't seem to run

Comment: again, this is Sprite Kit not cocos2d

Comment: yes, but you are already past that point (`if (self.scene.view.paused ==NO)`) when you set `self.scene.view.paused = YES`… are you meaning, in the following, not shown parts of the touchesBegan method?

Comment: Basically what i tried doing is: IF (scene is PLAYING), I want to show the PAUSE button on top and when someone clicks that button- scene is set to paused. and when (SCENE IS PAUSED), player should see the play button, and when he clicks it, he should be able to play the scene....

Comment: What's with the timer and why are you not using a simple IF statement to set one state or the other?